# How to sync new object (weapons/bullet) in a multiplayer photon game ?

Tags: unity, multiplayer, photon

I'm using Photon to develop a multiplayer game. 
I would like to know the best way to synchronize "weapons" bullets object between network players.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to continuosly sync the position of your bullets, you only need to know when and where a bullet was fired. This should be fine for most cases:

```
[PunRPC]
private void Fire(Vector3 pos, Vector3 dir)
{
    Instantiate(Resources.Load("Bullet"), pos, dir);

    if(this.photonView.isMine)
    {
        this.photonView.RPC("Fire", PhotonTargets.OthersBuffered, pos, dir);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, this simply transform a normal method in a "networked" Photon RPC method ? Thanks !